# Reliable alternative of LOCATION_MODE for KitKat and above to get the degree of location access enabled by the user?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-location, android-settings

**What I'm trying to do:**

Since [LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED) was depreciated in `API` level 19, I am trying to use [LOCATION_MODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE) to get the degree of location access enabled by the user for `API` above 19 as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    int locationMode;
    try {
        locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        // Check if Location services in ON and if YES then make sure its in either HIGH_ACCURACY or POWER_SAVING mode (Not in GPS_ONLY)
        switch (locationMode) {
            case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF:
            //....
            break;

            case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY:
            //....
            break;

            //....
        }
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

Now, for [LOCATION_MODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE), the docs mention

> Note: do not rely on this value being present in `settings.db` or on `ContentObserver` notifications for the corresponding Uri.

By what I can understand, it means that its not reliable to use `LOCATION_MODE`. Then for `API` > 19, what else is recommended to use for knowing the extent to location access that has been allowed by user for the apps?